# suitable substitution in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the help of jquery I've done the following for changing the color of the row on clicking a checkbox,all the checkbox is having same class name, the code is working fine, but the requirement in one of our project was to do this using simple pure  javascript (no library)

can anyone please tell me some solution for this

```
$(".cbxSelect").click(function (e) {
    if (!$(this).closest('tr').hasClass("myclass")) {
        $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'yellow');
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass("myclass");
    } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'white');
        $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("myclass");
    }
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/Kph8M/8/**

Comment: Define "simple JavaScript". Why are you adding and removing `myclass` *and* adding and removing the background color?

Comment: i mean pure js (no library)....but how can i code the above thing in pure js without library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.cbxSelect');

for (var i=boxes.length; i--;) {
    boxes[i].addEventListener('change', handler, false);
}

function handler() {
    var el = this;
    while (el.parentNode) {
        el = el.parentNode;
        if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'tr') {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (el.getAttribute('data-color') != 'yellow') {
        el.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
        el.setAttribute('data-color', 'yellow');
    }else{
        el.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        el.setAttribute('data-color', 'white');
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kph8M/10/)

Answer (score 2):

Since you already toggle `myclass` it makes sense to use it for background color:

```
.myclass {
    background: yellow;
}
```

and JS:

```
var checks = document.querySelectorAll('.cbxSelect');

for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
    checks[i].onchange = function() {
        var tr = this.parentNode.parentNode;
        if (/\bmyclass\b/.test(tr.className)) {
            tr.className = tr.className.replace(/\bmyclass\b/g, '');
        }
        else {
            tr.className += ' myclass';
        }
    };
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/Kph8M/12/